# How to verify if quantity exists before update

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert

I want to create a trigger or a stored procedure that throws an error if the quantity that the user tries to insert in an order is bigger than the available quantity.

So basically, I have 2 tables: Order_Product which has OrderId, Product_Id and Quantity, and Inventory which has Product_Id and Quantity. So if the user tries to insert a row for a specific product_id in Order_Product with a quantity bigger than the quantity available for the same product_id in Inventory, to throw an error before the insert.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I lean toward a trigger and signal https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: *if the user tries to insert a row for a specific product_id in Order_Product with a quantity bigger than the quantity available for the same product_id in Inventory* Does the user may insert 2 rows which matches separately but oversize in a sum? is this legal?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following trigger does what you want:

```
delimiter //

create trigger trg_order_product_insert
before insert on order_product
for each row
begin
    if (new.quantity > (select quantity from inventory where product_id = new.product_id)) then
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'not enough quantity available in inventory';
    end if;
end
//

delimiter ;
```

With this set up at hand, you also need to think about how to keep the available quantity up to date in the `inventory` table. You might want to add an `update` statement to the above trigger, that decrements the inventory of the product.

Comment: Thank you ! I already have one trigger who does it but only after the insert on the order_product table.